# Connect from popup.html to background.js script in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Connect from `popup.html` to `background.js` script in Chrome Extension.
When I click on the button, I want the background script to open a new tab.

Background Script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {    
    if (message == "output") {

       var win = window.open('https://www.google.ca/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjesaKd26TcAhWNw4MKHcN-CwgQPAgD', '_blank');
       win.focus();    
    }    
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <script src="next.js"></script> 
    <input id="output" type="button" value="Go To Alternative Forum"/>
</body>
```

Next:

```
 document.getElementById("output").addEventListener(("click"),function(){

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage("output"); 
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question and code in the post body? Consider using a code snippet.

Comment: my bad. its my first time. just did. and its regarding a chrome popup.html extension.

Comment: Shouldn't the script have src="" instead of href=""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by window.open.

But if you want to do connect your html to background.js, then the official way is to send the message from your script next.js to the background.js and then background.js will create new tab to open the link.

Following code will work in your case:

**next.js**

```
 document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click",function(){

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "openTab",value:code},function(response) {

        });

    });
```

**popup.html**

```
<body>
    <script src="next.js"></script>
    <input id="next" type="button" value="Go to google" />
</body>
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.type == "openTab") {

        chrome.tabs.create({"url": "http://www.google.com", "selected": true}, function (tab) {

        });

    }

});
```

Comment: this code makes alot more sense. however, i am unable to connect my html to the next.js. the addEventListener dosen't connect. but thank you

Comment: I apologize. There was an error in eventlistener line. I've updated the code. It should work now.

Comment: i feel it nessary to imply that the next file is not the content script. do i need to add anything to the manifest.json.

Answer (score 1):

Your script reference in your code should have a src="" attribute instead of a href="". Example here:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <script src="next.js"></script>
    <input onclick="start();" type="button" value="Go to google" />
</body>
```

next.js:

```
function start() {
    var win = window.open('https://www.google.ca/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjesaKd26TcAhWNw4MKHcN-//CwgQPAgD', '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

Comment: thanks that helps. but i dont think the popup.html can connect to the background script. due to the fact its a chrome cast. thanks tho